# JavaScript - examples of reduce() function

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm looking at this example of use of the `reduce()` function.

```
function add(runningTotal, currentValue) {
   return runningTotal + currentValue;
}

var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = nums.reduce(add);
print(sum); // displays 55
```

Could you give show me some other examples of using reduce() - I'm not sure I fully follow how it works.

Comment: Any other example is likely to confuse you more. That example is the most basic, easily understood use.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: The actual implementation of `Array.prototype.reduce` may give yet more info: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/70c4bf13315145be89e9f8b7f4313fab2442dcda/src/js/array.js#L1480

Comment: I'm just confused on what reduce() does. The add() function confuses me as well. The add function requires 2 arguments but when fed to the reduce function, add function has no argument. Would you explain in works how it all works?

Comment: That's because it's a reference to a function passed to the `nums.reduce()`. Then the `Array.prototype.reduce` implementation takes that reference to a function and invokes it on every element (and passes 4 arguments to be precise).

Comment: @Wasteland https://pastee.org/jugbz maybe this example make it more clear if one just concatenate strings instead of summing numbers. What `reduce` does? Essentially it takes `nums` array and process each element of the array and it keeps a temporary result (`runningTotal`) all the way until all elements of the array are processed. So the `reduce` function is a good way if you want to process all elements of the array and the result is a single value (a number, a string, ...)  (it's more powerful than that but to make it simple). If you don't like `reduce`, you can always replaceItWithAForLoop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What reduces does is take an `initialValue`, a `function` with 2 essential parameters (can take more) and a `list` of values. If no `initialValue` is provided then it's assumed it's the first element of the list. The function is supposed to do something with the `previousValue` usually used as an accumulator and the `nextValue`.

So, assume you have a list of values: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and the function is supposed to add the 2 parameters and an `initialValue` of `0`.

First step:

```
0 + 1 = 1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

Second step:

```
1 + 2 = 3
    3
    4
    5
```

Third Step:

```
3 + 3 = 6
    4
    5
```

Fourth Step:

```
6 + 4 = 10
    5
```

Fifth Step:

```
10 + 5 = 15 //Final value
```

As you can see, the input went from a `list` to a single value, hence the name `reduce`. In your example, there's no `initialValue` (that's the second argument), so it's as if started on the second step.

Comment: I think it's making sense now. It's really no much different than: function myAdd(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
 sum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log("for: " + sum);
}

myAdd(nums);

Comment: Right that would produce the same result, however notice that `reduce` is more generic. In my example it does `x + y` on every step, that's the function supplied. It's really doing `f(x, y)` on every step. `f` can be much more than just adding up values.

Answer (score 4):

You can set second argument for reduce

```js
function add(runningTotal, currentValue) {
   return runningTotal + currentValue;
}
var someInitValue = 10
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = nums.reduce(add, someInitValue);
console.log(sum); // displays 65
```

Comment: And even further - it makes sense to always specify the initial value.

Answer (score 4):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works by iterating over an array and calling a reductor function (this function is the first argument passed to `reduce()`.  This function has four arguments:

- `previousValue`, which is sort of a 'running total'.  this is initially undefined, unless you provide a seed value as the second argument to `reduce()`.
- `currentValue` which is an object in your array
- `index` of the current value in your array
- `array`, the array itself

when your reductor function is called, its return value becomes the new `previousValue` argument for *next time* the reductor function is called.  that's the magic.  after the reductor function is called and given the very last object in the array, its return value will be the return value of `reduce()`.

honestly, a lot of the examples you'll see (like using `reduce()` to sum up a bunch of integers) are pretty easy to do with a `for()` loop.  its real value is when you're doing [functional programming](http://redsymbol.net/articles/crash-course-applied-functional-programming/).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use reduce to do things like generate some kind of stream cipher.

```
var plaintext = "thisisaplaintext";
var chars = plaintext.split('');
var result = '';
function encrypt(runningTotal, currentValue){
    var newVal = ((runningTotal + (""+runningTotal).charCodeAt()-32) % 94)+32
    result  = result + String.fromCharCode(newVal)
    return newVal;
}
chars.reduce(encrypt, 15 /*any arbitrary starting value*/);
console.log(result);
```

Basically, anything that can be made with a combination of independent calculations or anything that requires some rolling total. It's nothing that you couldn't already do with a for loop, but it looks cleaner.