# Find the longest string from an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects called `rows`, where each object has a string property called `name`.

I would like to get the longest `name`. How can I filter `rows` and grab the row with the longest name, or grab the name itself. Thank you!

Lodash or vanilla JS both work for my purposes.  If there are 2 strings tied for the longest length, grabbing either string works for my purposes.

Comment: Sort it by length then grab the first one ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const rows = [
  {
    name: "bar",
  },
  {
    name: "foobar",
  },
  {
    name: "ba",
  },
];

const firstItem = rows
  .slice()
  .sort((a, b) => (a.name.length > b.name.length ? -1 : 1))[0];

console.log(firstItem.name); // Outputs 'foobar'
```

**Note:** I'm slicing the array to avoid mutating it in place

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine:

```js
rows.sort((x,y) => y.name.length - x.name.length)[0]
```

This will mutate the data. You can make a copy of it if you don't want to sort the original `rows` array. But keep an eye out for not mutating any returned object either as that will mutate the original too. If you don't want that, then you need to do a deep copy.

For example,

```js
const rows = [{name: 'abcde'}, {name: 'abc'}, {name: 'abcd'}];

// spreading rows will essentially make a copy of `rows`    
const result = [...rows].sort((x,y) => y.name.length - x.name.length)[0]

console.log(result); // this will print `{name: 'abcde'}`

result.name = 123; // mutating the resulting object after making a copy

console.log(rows); // this will be mutated now
```

Same with `slice()` and `concat()`. They will make a shallow copy too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Array.prototype.reduce` and keep the longest string.

```
rows.reduce((longest, current) => longest.name.length > current.name.length ? longest : current);
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but if someone is asking this question, I'd suggest they are enough of a beginner that you probably shouldn't introduce `reduce` yet.

Comment: On that note, here's another answer for an [explanation of reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600900/javascript-examples-of-reduce-function/34601117#34601117)